# schema free solution to BigQuery Load job

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

#### Background

I studied and found that bigQuery doesn't accept schemas defined by online tools (which have different formats, even though meaning is same).
So, I found that if I want to load data (where no. of columns keeps varying and increasing dynamically) into a table which has a fixed schema.

#### Thoughts

What i could do as a workaround is:

1. First check if the data being loaded has extra fields.
2. If it has, a schema mismatch will occur, so first you create a temporary table in BQ and load this data into the table using "autodetect" parameter, which gives me a schema (that is in a format,which BQ accepts schema files).
3. Now i can download this schema file and use it,to update my exsisting table in BQ and load it with appropriate data.

#### Suggestion

Any thoughts on this, if there is a better approach please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are in the process of releasing a new feature that can update the schema of the destination table within a load/query job. With autodetect and the new feature you can directly load the new data to the existing table, and the schema will be updated as part of the load job. Please stay tuned. The current ETA is 2 weeks.

Comment: :),looking forward to this

Comment: The feature is live in the server now. We had a glitch on the command-line client so it'll be released probably next week. Please try it out and let us know if you ran into any problems. Thanks. Documentation is at: 

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.schemaUpdateOptions

Comment: Awesome work,Yesterday i had the opportunity to test it.!

Comment: its not working...i was able to do it early morning,but it seems not working now.!...:(

Comment: Here is my load configuration and here is my error received.

Comment: Column description is not a required field and I don't think that error message is thrown by BQ. Are you using some other tools that requires column description?